# Excel VBA Application.Visible = false not working on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, excel, userform, vba

I want my Workbook to not be visible when my userform is active.

I am able to make this work on a Windows machine by setting Application.Visible = False on the userForm initialize method and True on the UserForm Exit.

The same workbook does not behave the same way on a mac. The workbook remains visible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not know why Application.Visible = False does not work on Mac OSX, the following was able to address my needs:

On User Form initialize - 
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

On User Form Terminate - 
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized